# Jenkins 2.89.2 and launching slaves via script on master

Tags: jenkins

I have a Jenkins system where I connect to slaves using a custom command which is run on master.
It seems that with version 2.89.2 this option has been removed from the UI, only allowing SSH, Java Web Start or Windows server.

Is this intentional? Is there a way to restore the previous behavior?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue after the update as well - broke all my agents. Looking at the patch notes this is an intentional change, as the functionality has been moved into a new plugin:

https://plugins.jenkins.io/command-launcher

Installing this should restore the old behaviour.